# Python . Select transparent colour or no colour for lines / points etc

Tags: python

How do I plot a line of transparent colour or no colour ?

For example :

plot(x,y,color='transparent')

or

plot(x,y,color='None')

BTW , color='white' is not what I'm looking for .

Thanks in advance invisible computer people .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming matplotlib, from the "How-to" in the docs: http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html

```
ax.plot(x, y, alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: `plot(x, y, alpha=0)` for full transparency. @Derek, what is the library you are using btw ?

Comment: I am using Pylab . alpha=0 works , it gives me a transparent line . thanks Sivatumma . alpha=0.5 doesn't work though . Sorry M4rtini it gives me a light blue line . Actually that's what i tried initially as i've seen a few people mention it elsewhere but it doesn't work for me for some reason . Thanks though .

Answer (score 1):

Try color = '#FF000000' its the Hex code.